# $A$ relatively compact $\iff$ $A$ is bounded and limit of supremum of $A$ goes to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, compactness

Let $1\leq p < \infty$ and $A \subseteq \ell^{p}$. Show that:

$A$ relatively compact $\iff$ $A$ is bounded and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sup\limits_{x \in A}(\sum\limits_{i=n}^{\infty}\vert x_{i}\vert^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}=0$

"$\Rightarrow$" Assume $A$ is relatively compact, then $\overline{A}$ is compact and hence totally bounded, the fact that $A \subseteq \overline{A}$ immediately shows that $A$ is also totally bounded and therefore bounded.

And I think I need to solve $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sup\limits_{x \in A}(\sum\limits_{i=n}^{\infty}\vert x_{i}\vert^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}=0$ via contradiction. So, assume there exists $c>0$ so that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sup\limits_{x \in A}(\sum\limits_{i=n}^{\infty}\vert x_{i}\vert^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}=c$ then we can find a sequence $(x^{m})_{m} \subseteq A$ so that $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\sum\limits_{i=n}^{\infty}\vert x_{i}^{m}\vert^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}$ but his just makes it overly complicated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prove the last part directly.

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Use the fact that $A$ is totally bounded to get a finite set of sequences $\{x^k\}$ such that $A\subset \bigcup_k B(x^k,\epsilon)$.

Define the tail norm as $\|\cdot \|_{p,n}$.

Then for each $k$, find $N_k$ such that $\|x^k\|_{p,N_k}<\epsilon$.

Let $N$ be the max of the $N_k$.

For every $x\in A$, let $k_x$ denote the index of the sequence $x^{k_x}$ that is closest to $x$ in the $p$-norm.

We then have $\|x-x^{k_x}\|_{p,N} \leq \|x-x^{k_x}\|_{p} < \epsilon$, so

\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in A} \|x\|_{p,N}
& \leq
\sup_{x\in A} \|x-x^{k_x}\|_{p,N} + \|x^{k_x}\|_{p,N} \\
& \leq
2\epsilon
\end{align}